# Passing CFLAGS to configure via bash variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, configure

Just when I think I know how the shell works fairly, something comes along and stumps me. The following commands were executed on GNU bash, version 3.2.25.

I have several `./configure` scripts that all share a group of common configure options, one of them being `CFLAGS`.

To that end, I have two variables

```bsh
CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"
COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="CFLAGS=\"$CFLAGS\" --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=$PREFIX"
```

When this gets passed to `./configure', it is done so like,

```bsh
"$FOO/configure" $COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS
```

For the life of me, I cannot seem to get this to expand correctly. I have tried manually substituting the value of `$CFLAGS` into `$COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS`. I have tried every combination of single and double quotes under the sun. I have even tried quoting the entire "CFLAGS=..." argument.

The version I gave above yields the following (when `set -x` is enabled)

```
../configure 'CFLAGS="-fPIC' '-O3"' --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=../install
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-O3"'
Try `../configure --help' for more information
```

What I expected, and what I desire, is for `configure` to be invoked like

```
./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3" --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix="$PREFIX"
```

How can I achieve what I want, and additionally, are there good resources/tips on how to avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: What do you see if you echo it rather than pass it to configure? Does running: `./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3" --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix="$PREFIX"` work as expected?

Comment: `echo $COMMON_CONFIGURE OPTIONS` yields `CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3" --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=../install`. And yes, manually substituting the variables works as expected.

Comment: Maybe try escaping the space or using single quotes in the second variable: `COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="CFLAGS='$CFLAGS' --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=$PREFIX"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work :

```
CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3" ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix="$PREFIX"
```

Second option:

```
CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"
COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=$PREFIX"

CFLAGS="$CFLAGS" ./configure $COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS
```

Comment: It's not that this doesn't work, it's that I have to do this for several configure commands. It's possible to just copy/paste the configure flags, but this is overly tedious when testing and making changes to the script.

Comment: That second option wouldn't be so bad. As I explained in another comment, it turned out that `CFLAGS` was not sufficient to solve my issue (I had to use `--with-pic` instead), but this would have been acceptable otherwise.

Comment: Although, I'm not sure if it's redundant at that point, since you've already set `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Agree, it's a little redundant. The idea is to integrate in your workflow. You have "COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="CFLAGS=\"$CFLAGS\"..." in your post

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. The original `CFLAGS` substitution in my post was probably redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"
COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="CFLAGS=\"$CFLAGS\" --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=$PREFIX"
...
"$FOO/configure" $COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS
```

That's quite off, first because the shell does NOT keep expanding stuff recursively (as `make` does with its macros, except that `make` doesn't "unquote" them, ever):

```
a=A; b="B=\"$a\""; printf '<%s>\n' "$b"
<B="A">
```

and second, because unquoted variables will be split with the characters from `IFS` (whitespaces by default), which doesn't care about quotes:

```
a="x \"y z\""; printf '<%s>\n' $a
<x>
<"y>
<z">
```

You can of course, use

```
eval "$FOO/configure" "COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS"
```

(notice the double quotes around both variables), but that will open another can of worms, and you **SHOULD NOT** use such tricks unless you have a very firm grip of the whole parsing and expanding mechanism and all its quirks which, no offense intended, you don't seem to.

The solution is to forget about the `$COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` nonsense and pass all those options separately:

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix="$PREFIX" CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"
```

Comment: "The shell does not keep expanding stuff recursively." So when I define `COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS`, it doesn't expand the contents of `CFLAGS`? I was under the assumption that since the value is in double quotes that it would. To be clear, I don't want or expect that `COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` contain the value `$CFLAGS` that would be expanded when I expand `COMMON_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Your mention of `IFS` seems like the right answer, however. I'll have to try the expansion with `IFS=`

Comment: By expansion, I was meaning the whole process (quote removal, split + glob, etc) not just. I will change the first example to better match yours. And no, setting or unsetting IFS will not help you: configure doesn't expect all those options as a single argument.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass them all as a single argument. The shell variable should expand to multiple arguments. I don't understand the objection considering this works perfectly fine with regular flags like `--enable-shared`. 

Either way, I found the correct solution to my issue lay outside of directly passing `CFLAGS="-fPIC"` (`--with-pic` was the correct `configure` flag in this scenario.)

Comment: No, the shell "should" not do that. There's no way to pass a variable whose value is `a="b c" --foo d="e f"` as the 3 arguments `a=b c`, `--foo` and `d=e f` _without_ using eval. And configure doesn't expect `CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"` (with the quotes), but `CFLAGS=-fPIC -O3` as a _single_ argument.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, I didn't mean the shell *should* do that. That's exactly what my shell does when a variable has spaces in it. This is why I always quote variables that may contain spaces. I would be very surprised if I was doing this for no reason, considering this exact concern is echoed in every guide to shell scripting I've ever read.

Comment: I just re-read your comment. I don't want the quotes to disappear. `a=b c` is wrong. `a="b c"` is what I intended. But clearly I don't understand the shell well enough to do that, and it turns out to be unnecessary. Still surprised at how difficult a task it seems to be to achieve that result.

Comment: No, you don't intend `CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"`; configure will choke on it. You're confused by the way `set -x` displays the commands. The task would be very simple provided that you gave up on your preconceived notions, and not try to overcomplicate it ;-)

Comment: Oh, the task is done. As I said in a previous comment, `CFLAGS` was not the correct solution in this case. Besides, what do you mean `configure` will choke? If you run `./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"` it works just fine. I don't mean to sound rude, but you keep telling me things don't work that do and suggesting solutions that wouldn't have worked for my use-case. So please don't be offended if I sound combative or frustrated.

Comment: `./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"` will NOT pass `CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"` as an argument to `./configure`, but `CFLAGS=-fPIC -O3`. Go read 50 times the [`EXPANSION`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) section of bash's manual, and 100 times its `Quote Removal` subsection, then come back. All the things I've told you DO WORK because I've TESTED THEM. As to your "usage case": if you cared to make your script flexible, you would a wrapper func like `cfg(){ ./configure ... whatever default options .. "$@"; }` instead of blindly quote stuffing and escaping.

Comment: I see now what we're arguing over is a misunderstanding. When I said `a="b c"` was what I wanted, I did not mean I wanted `argv` of `./configure` to contain the quoted string `CFLAGS="-fPIC -O3"`, I meant that I wanted the invocation of the command to appear as such, so that `argv` would contain `CFLAGS=-fPIC -O3`. But anyways, this is a waste of time. My problem is already solved, and your continual insistence that I don't know what I'm doing is insulting. Thanks for trying to help.